# Can we get a Stack Exchange addition to Markdown to allow inline spoilers?

Tags: feature-request, spoilers

There are lots of questions in the Puzzling Meta about coded comments, suggesting that there's a demand for spoiler blocks within comments. The spoiler block is already a Stack Exchange addition to Markdown. Is it possible to get a similar addition to allow inline spoilers/spoilers in comments? One possible implementation would be an HTML tag <spoiler>like so</spoiler>.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371270/can-we-get-extended-spoiler-functionality/371274#371274

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do we want extended spoiler functionality?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7242/do-we-want-extended-spoiler-functionality)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This is really a question for the main meta site.
- One obvious problem as presented is that HTML tags don't work in comments.
- If enough people agree on a standard though, it could be done unofficially using a browser extension.
  (E.g. `marker encoded-text marker`, where the extension would decode the text when it's clicked, such as using hex character values:`SPOILER-X(4578616d706c65)` → `Example`, or `SPOILER-13(rot13text)`.

Comment: We already have a [rot13 user script](https://bitbucket.org/alconja/user-scripts/src/59d09d305a39764041edec543ded38bbcd2b1fa3/).

Comment: @LukasRotter, does it work in comments?

Comment: It only works in comments AFAIK, since it would be useless in post bodies anyway.